# How to run Webpack Dev Server --https --hot --inline

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

Is there a way to leverage running the webpack-dev-server on https when configuring using CLI?

> The problem is the connection to `socket.io` is over `http` and not `https`.

---

A workaround exists, but its very annoying.

1. Manually include **https** `webpack-dev-server` in your `index.html`

```html
<script src="https://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server.js"></script>
```

2. Configure each end point to include `webpack/hot/only-dev-server`.

```js
app: [
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    './app.js'
],

// ... more entry points that include the same [] ...
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes there is a way to configure webpack-dev-server on https when configuring using CLI.

The solution is to not use `--inline` option.

There are many ways to configure the server and `--hot`. The one to follow, assuming your not creating a custom server implementation/middleware (*Might be the same*), is detailed in the docs.

http://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#webpack-dev-server-cli

- **Do not** include `<script src="https://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server.js"></script>`
- **Do not** include `webpack/hot/only-dev-server` into the entry.

#### package.json

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server -d --hot --https --config webpack.config.development.js"
  }
}
```

#### webpack.config.development.js

```js
var webpackConfig = require('webpack-config');

module.exports = webpackConfig.fromCwd().merge({
    devServer: {
        colors:             true,
        contentBase:        './build',
        historyApiFallback: true,
        inline:             true,
        progress:           true
    },

    devtool: 'eval-source-map'
});
```

*Main webpack configuration is not listed here.*

Answer (score 1):

I think you might add this line to the entry point to also create a secure socket connection:

```
"dev-server": "webpack-dev-server/client?https://localhost:8080/",
```

Answer (score 0):

I used like this in `package.json` and started working with port i needed:

```
"scripts": {
  "serve": "webpack-dev-server --inline --colors --watch --display-error-details --display-cached  --port 3001 --hot"
},
```