# Webpack SSL certificate on localhost

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ssl, webpack

Is there a way to use an SSL certificate in my reactJS app on localhost with webpack?

I've added

```
--https
```

in start script ... that looks good. but then I got this error:

[image]

Comment: Did you check this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26663404/webpack-dev-server-running-on-https-web-sockets-secure