# How to enable https for webpack-dev-server with own certificate?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack-dev-server

I'm building a react app and I'd like to use let's encrypt certificate for webpack-dev-server. Can I use own certificates (`.pem` files) and pass it for webpack-dev-server config?

Comment: Do you want to enable https for webpack-dev-server?

Comment: Yes I want to enable it for that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It will depend on how you are packaging your app for deployment to production, and whether you will use a load balancer (which typically handles https for you). You need to provide information about your desired target environment for us to help you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Webpack Dev Server running on HTTPS/Web Sockets Secure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26663404/webpack-dev-server-running-on-https-web-sockets-secure)

Comment: At the moment I am using docker for it. I made the image, in the Dockerfile I'll add the certificate files to the project. But after I don't know where to set the paths to those files. So far in the dockerfile I just included the files of the project and run npm start.

Comment: For dev configuration you typically use url based on localhost or 127.0.0.1. Let-s-encrypt do not provide certificate for such base. But for domains. (Or provide link where you have read that)

Comment: @asiweb you can try this https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/tree/master/examples/cli/https#using-your-certificate

Answer (score 1):

in the webpack.config.js do the following :

```js
const fs = require('fs');
//...
module.exports = {
  //...
  devServer: {
    https: {
      key: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/server.key'),
      cert: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/server.crt'),
      ca: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/ca.pem'),
    },
  },
};
```