# webpack-dev-server: auto reload for tampermonkey script

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, tampermonkey

I am trying to get `webpack-dev-server` auto-reload a script I am writing to run as userscript in Tampermonkey with the `webpack-userscript` plugin. I suspect the problem is that the script does run in an external website and not on localhost, so I don't know if this is possible at all.

I observed that the script is trying to make requests to `https://<external website host>:8080/sockjs-node/` instead of `ws://localhost:8080/sockjs-node`. I tried to use a proxy in the dev-server config, but it doesn't work and I'm not sure if this is actually the right approach.

```
devServer: {
   contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
   proxy: {
      '/sockjs-node': {
         target: 'ws://localhost:8080',
         secure: false,
         ws: true,
      },
   },
},
```

One thing I observed after setting up the proxy the request changed from `https://<external website host>:8080/sockjs-node/` to `https://localhost:8080/sockjs-node/` and now it continues to request `https://localhost:8080/sockjs-node/` even when I remove the proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more trial and error I found the solution. The problem was that the external site was served over https and browsers prevent unsecure socket connections for these sites.

So I had to configure the dev server to use https as well, but the default self-signed certificate isn't enough. Per [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54843904/2830131) I created a root CA and a certificate for localhost with mkcert (on Windows I had to manually add the root CA into the browser's certificate store) and then the configuration was simply:

```
devServer: {
   contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
   disableHostCheck: true,
   https: {
      key: readFileSync(path.resolve('../../localhost-key.pem')),
      cert: readFileSync(path.resolve('../../localhost.pem')),
      ca: readFileSync(path.join(os.homedir(), 'AppData/Local/mkcert/rootCA.pem')),
   },
},
```