# Webpack log errors "net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR" by calling sockjs-node/info

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, .net-core

on front I use `react` on back `.net core 3.1`

on client I use webpack that is runned on `localhost:8080`

in Startup.cs I use proxyToSpa

```
 applicationBuilder.UseSpa(spa =>
                {
                    spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:8080/");
                });
```

on HTTP works as expected without any errors but on HTTPS I saw a lot of console errors and failed requests in Network there is failed requests for (`sockjs-node/info?t=`...) with error `net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`

[image]
[image]

Is there any options to configure webpack or .net core project to avoid these error logs on HTTPS?

Answer (score 2):

This might be the issue, it worked for me

https://howchoo.com/chrome/stop-chrome-from-automatically-redirecting-https

If you ever visited the https version of a website (whether it resolved or not), Google Chrome might repeatedly send you to that version

Answer (score 1):

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverdisablehostcheck

using cli

```
webpack-dev-server --disable-host-check
```

or in webpack config

```
devServer: {
        disableHostCheck: true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My main site was using https (reverse proxy to development server), so definining public: http://... didn't help for my development server, because the browser forced https (as the main site was https to).

**What helped me was using https in the devServer too**:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29772748/3279070

It was important that devServer HTTPS was signed with a good certificate like the main site was (the reverse proxy) and uses a hostname (public property) signed by the cert. So for example typical scenario is using the same certificate files and the same hostname (public: 'https://hostname:8081')  as the main site