# Facebook JavaScript SDK: FB.init and FB.getLoginStatus always return the status 'unknown' and reset status in session

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

**Circumstance:**

I am trying all of this in development mode under `http://localhost ...`,
I allow all cookies on my Chrome, I haven't implemented `FB.logout` in the code, for every experiments I did below, I manually clean all of the sessions, and cookies before the next experiment. I am using a temporary user provided by the developer platform.

**Problem:**.

First, my settings with `FB.init`:

```js
FB.init({
  appId  :  'my-app-id',
  xfbml  :   true,
  version: 'v8.0',
  status :  true,
 });
```

With these settings, I can see the Facebook user status in my Session Storage

```js
authResponse: null
expiresAt: 1603788619414
status: "unknown"
```

Then by using `FB.login`, I can get a response with user in `connected` status.

```js
FB.login((response) => {
  console.log(response)
  //  {
  //    authResponse: {
  //      accessToken: "..."
  //      data_access_expiration_time: 1611478982
  //      expiresIn: 7018
  //.     graphDomain: "facebook"
  //      signedRequest: "..."
  //    },
  //.   status: "connected",
  //. }
})
```

The status in my Session Storage also reflects this result.

But then I refresh the page, the status in the session is set to `unknown` again.
Under this situation, I open a new tab to a Facebook page, my test user is logged in, if I trigger the FB.login on my site again, I don't have to go through the dialog to offer my email/password again, but the status in session would be set to 'connected'.

So seems every time I refresh my site, the `FB.init` sets the status to `unknown` even the user is actually logged in.

I do another experiment with FB.getLoginStatus:

```js
FB.login((response) => {
  FB.getLoginStatus((response) => {
    // ...
  });
});
```

```js
FB.login((response) => {
  FB.getLoginStatus((response) => {
    // ...
  }, true);
});
```

- First case:
  The response in the callback of FB.getLoginStatus has the result with `status: connected`.
- Second case:
  I get the response with status: connected in `FB.login`'s response, but with roundtrip to Facebook server is forced for `FB.getLoginStatus`, the response of it turns to `status: unknown`, also the session is set to `status: unknown`.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems are resolved after I setup **https** on my local development.
(I really wish this could be documented in the [Facebook for Developers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/))

I am developing my project with React + Webpack, for people who are with the same stacks, here is a good reference you may need:
[Webpack Dev Server running on HTTPS/Web Sockets Secure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54843904/4365123)